# How to: disable Line-Wrap; and enable Horizontal-Scrolling; in an Android EditText Control

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried a few answers i have found here on SO, and Google, but nobody seems to produce a workable solution.

I am an old HTML guy; so for me the solution is simple, find the css, implement the code. Android is so.... there really is no good word for the mess the Android team has made. Perhaps "Amateur" is the correct word for screw ups of this nature.

All "we" want to do, is enable horizontal scrolling in a multiple line text-edit[=EditText] user input control, and disable the automatic paragraph/line-breaking and word-splitting (which one would think, is vanilla-behavior; but isn't).

I can't read my "logcat" output because Android thinks "encrypting" my data with a line compression algorithm is the best and only most useful way to "view" a text..

If you can provide a bare-layout with no special java code hacks that provides this functionality I will accept your solution as the "answer" on a first-come-first-serve-basis.

Comment: Have you tried using [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)?

Comment: yes, didnt work, and does not make sense. why are there scrollbar controls on the TextEdit, if you need to use a scroll view?

Comment: i guess the best thing to do is get the source, and create the settings the amatuers neglected to create.

Comment: even if a horizontal scroller is the solution, i dont think i could live with the lack of sanity in running code that makes no sense. and for the life of me, I cannot figure out how anyone was paid/elected/appointed/otherwise given the authority to do such a thing on a production system.

Comment: Add some code and the methods that you have tried.

Comment: that would not pertain to the question i have asked.

Comment: I don't think it can be done for a multiline EditText and I don't see the point either. Can you tell us what the use case is?

Comment: if you cant read, how can you help me? "I can't read my "logcat" output because Android thinks "encrypting" my data with a line compression algorithm is the best and only most useful way to "view" a text.."

Comment: Well that was rude.

Comment: furthermire your "opinion" of what i want to do, and my actual use case are not in concern of the real question. android runs on large and small screen devices. so tell me where our opinions of how text should be shown in apps we are not writing is ever going to matter? cuz i dont get what you are saying.

Comment: i assume that you have tried Sriram, and if you have i thank you for confirming my suspicion; that such a thing is not technically achievable. THE FACTS would have been worth far more than YOUR OPINION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with an answer for this question by adapting other answers.

My answer uses constraint layout for the main viewgroup.

The disabling of the line wrap, is intrinsically tied to enabling horizontal growth of the underlying textview=editText. I have tested this solution on phone and tablet. My original answer did not address an unforseen issue with input method editor compatibility; where the IME was still forcing line breaks; this code operates as intended in the original answer, providing for a multi-line textview with no line wrapping and horizontal scrolling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hypersoft.systems.texteditor.MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```